# -bash: /usr/bin/svn: No such file or directory

Tags: macos, terminal, bash, homebrew

I am trying to upgrade my svn version. So I deleted older binary

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/svn
```

Then I installed svn

```
brew install svn
```

And linked it too

```
athakur:home athakur$ brew link --overwrite subversion
Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/subversion/1.9.4
To relink: brew unlink subversion && brew link subversion
```

But when I do svn --version it says

```
athakur:home athakur$ svn
-bash: /usr/bin/svn: No such file or directory
```

Any idea how do I restore new svn binary?

Comment: Well home-brew won't update or change anything in /usr/bin what directory does Homebrew documentation say it will be in?

Comment: @Mark looks like it is in `/usr/local/Cellar/subversion/1.9.4/bin`

Comment: See the related questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like homebrew installed svn in

```
/usr/local/Cellar/subversion/1.9.4
```

So I added it in $PATH

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/subversion/1.9.4/bin/
```

Added it in `~/.bash_profile`. Then execute -

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

and all seems good again

Answer (score 0):

Here are the SVN binary packages: https://subversion.apache.org/packages.html

I had previously faced a similar issue and this solved the issue for me.

Also, when I tried using brew I had an issue, so I used MacPorts.